# Как передать Cookie при отправке запроса используя WebRequest

Tags: c#

Есть код, в котором я создаю реквест, перехожу по ссылке и получаю html страницы. Поскольку я НЕ знаю как можно залогиниться на сайте с помощью реквеста та и сам код мне написили хочу спросить. Могу ли я как то передать мои куки с веббраузера? (где я вручную залогинился)

Проблема в том, что мне передает html страницы, которая видна гостю, а не пользователю сайта.

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

    var dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    webResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом это не очень хорошая практика, но поскольку вы спрашиваете, то вот примерный код:

```
    private string site = "YourSite.example.com";
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;//это для скрытия ошибок в веб браузере
        webBrowser1.Navigate(site);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(site);//здесь можно заменить на какой-то другой адресс этого сайта
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        string str = webBrowser1.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        Uri uri = webBrowser1.Document.Url;

        string cookies = GetGlobalCookies(str);

        AddCookieToRequest(req, uri, cookies);
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            textBox1.Text = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    private void AddCookieToRequest(HttpWebRequest request,Uri uri, string cookies)
    {
        string[] cookiesPair = Regex.Split(cookies, ";");
        foreach (string cookisPair in cookiesPair)
        {
            string[] cookiesVal = Regex.Split(cookisPair, "=");
            if (cookiesVal.Length == 2) request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookiesVal[0].Trim(), cookiesVal[1].Trim()) { Domain = uri.Host });
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string pchURL, string pchCookieName, StringBuilder pchCookieData, ref uint pcchCookieData, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);
    private const int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0x00002000;

    public static string GetGlobalCookies(string uri)
    {
        uint datasize = 1024;
        StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder((int) datasize);
        if (InternetGetCookieEx(uri, null, cookieData, ref datasize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero) && cookieData.Length > 0)
        {
            return cookieData.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

В этом примере есть WinForms, на котором расположен WebBrowser, Button и Textbox. После загрузки формы начинает загружаться страница в WebBrowser. Вы входите в систему и нажимаете на кнопку после чего выполняется HttpWebRequest с использованием cookies из WebBrowser. Полученный результат выводиться текстом в текстбокс.

Код, который отделен взят [отсюда](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17366.get-cookies-from-webbrowser-controls-in-visual-c.aspx).

Функция AddCookieToRequest не самая оптимальная, ее бы лучше переписать, но для примера годится.