# Получить строку JSON от сайта

Tags: c#, json, http, get

Хочу получить расписание с сайта https://rasp.dmami.ru/. При переходе по ссылке https://rasp.dmami.ru/?151-331 и дальнешем разборе страницы через встроенный инструмент браузера получается получить JSON строку. Но как получить эту JSON и записать ее в переменную через свою программу?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://rasp.dmami.ru/site/group?group=151-331&session=0");
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "/";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36 OPR/62.0.3331.116";
        httpWebRequest.Referer = "https://rasp.dmami.ru/?151-331";
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json; var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented); или deserialize пробуйте

Comment: Суть в том, что на любой запрос к этой странице я получаю один и тот же ответ, который совсем не похож на JSON =(. Строку разобрать я смогу и сам, мне нужно ее как-то получить ) Сам result содержит это  - <html><body><script>document.cookie="bpc=a0c70ba7ec19f8e49a43db68467ff648;Path=/";document.location.href="https://rasp.dmami.ru/site/group?group=151-331&session=0";</script></body></html>

Comment: так вам надо с этим сервисом разбираться, а не json

Comment: В самом браузере без проблем получается получить эту строку при подобном запросе, а в программе совсем никак

Comment: возможно нужны специальные параметры в заголовке запроса к сервису

Comment: А их как-то можно узнать?

Comment: f12 и смотрите какой запрос на сервис отправляете когда из браузера получаете данные или fiddler-ом

Comment: В том то и дело, что запрос отправляется именно такой  Через ф12 я уже все посмотрел

Comment: возможно на их стороне ждут куки в заголовке. посмотрите это обсуждение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588627/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-cookie-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-webrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал пару запросов. Пришел к выводу:

1. Делаем запрос к `https://rasp.dmami.ru/site/group?group=151-331&session=0` с `Referer: https://rasp.dmami.ru/?151-331`
2. Далее в теле запроса идет установка кукиса, и далее перезагрузка страницы.
3. При перезагрузке страницы получается в ответе `json`.

Логично, нужно сделать запрос к странице, далее забрать кукис, установить его, и загрузить страницу снова с `Referer: https://rasp.dmami.ru/site/group?group=151-331&session=0`.

Прилагаю код:

```cs
#region Usings

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

#endregion
public class Program
{
    private static readonly CookieContainer CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    public static async Task<int> Main()
    {
        using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseCookies = true,
            CookieContainer = CookieContainer
        })
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri("https://rasp.dmami.ru/?151-331");

                using (HttpResponseMessage message =
                    await client.GetAsync("https://rasp.dmami.ru/site/group?group=151-331&session=0"))
                {
                    message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    Regex regex = new Regex("document.cookie=\\\"(?<CookieName>\\w+)\\=(?<CookieValue>.+?)\\;",
                        RegexOptions.Compiled);
                    Match cookieMatch = regex.Match(await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://rasp.dmami.ru/"),
                        new Cookie(cookieMatch.Groups["CookieName"].Value,
                            cookieMatch.Groups["CookieValue"].Value));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer =
                        new Uri("https://rasp.dmami.ru/site/group?group=151-331&session=0");

                    using (HttpResponseMessage responseJsonMessage =
                        await client.GetAsync("https://rasp.dmami.ru/site/group?group=151-331&session=0"))
                    {
                        responseJsonMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        Console.WriteLine(await responseJsonMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Ответ:

[image: some image]

Comment: Возникает ошибка 500

Comment: Да я пока пример писал, приложил готовый код.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я уже успел понять что в ошибке 500 виноват мой мобильный интернет который я раздаю себе на пк

Comment: 500 ошибка вам возвращалась когда вы игнорировали кукис, и `Referer`. Интернет здесь не причем.

Comment: А можно это без ассинхронности?

Comment: Вы хотите выполнять запросы в `UI` потоке?

Comment: Хотелось бы просто универсальную функцию, которая брала на вход адрес и запрос, а возвращала бы строку json